# How to remove an invalid local dependency from package-lock.json and package.json?

Tags: npm

Let's say that someone installed an invalid local dependency. (file does not exists locally)

package-lock.json

```
  "mock-framework": {
     "version": "file:../../../mock-framework",
```

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "mock-framework": "file:../../../mock-framework"
 }
```

I need to reinstall the framework, but it's located differently on my machine and does not follow the structure that was provided in the package locks. Because running the npm install command is giving me the error:

`Could not install from "../../../mock-framework" as it does not contain a package.json file.`

Would it be possible to clean it up through the command line? I tried with `npm uinstall` and still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I recently faced similar issue with local dependency integrity in `package-lock.json`

Ideally `npm uninstall` should remove the entry in `package-lock.json` but since it is not and you only have one local framework as changed dependency, you can try following -

Fix the dependency path and run `rm package-lock.json && npm i`

Hope I'm inline to your problem statement.

Comment: this is only a solution during development, you could mess up your production build with that. package-lock.json is there for a good reason.